# Character Convertor

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
turk = {"Ç":"C","ç":"c","Ğ":"G","ğ":"g","İ":"I","ı":"i",
        "Ö":"O","ö":"o","Ş":"S","ş":"s","Ü":"U","ü":"u"}

eng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \t1234567890"

space = " "

word = input("Enter a word")


def turkChar (word):
    newword = ""
    for c in word:
        if c in eng:
            newword = newword + c
        elif c in turk:
            newword = newword + turk[c]
        else:
            newword = newword + space
    return newword
```

I wrote this simple code which turns Turkish chars into English. I added space variable to make a space but what if user wants to make more space or tab or even numbers. How can I make this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should treat the space, tab and number characters any differently than your `eng` characters. I would simply extend your characters like this:

```py
eng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \t1234567890"
```

Then we can remove the 'space' parts, ending up with this:

```py
turk = {"Ç":"C","ç":"c","Ğ":"G","ğ":"g","İ":"I","ı":"i",
        "Ö":"O","ö":"o","Ş":"S","ş":"s","Ü":"U","ü":"u"}

eng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \t1234567890"

word = input("Enter a word")

def turkChar(word, turk):
    newword = ""
    for c in word:
        if c in eng:
            newword = newword + c
        elif c in turk:
            newword = newword + turk[c]
    return newword
```

- A tab character is written as `\t` in a string.
- Noticed you had a missing lower `h` in your `eng` string.
- You defined `turk` as an argument but not `eng`, either define both or neither.
- If character isn't found in `eng` nor `turk` then it's ignored.

Comment: Hmm I don't think it should fail. It works when I try it. Could you create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) of your usage example?

Answer (score 2):

Python has a string function called [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate) that is made for this and is very efficient (much more efficient than a loop/dict-lookup). You can make a translation table with a dictionary exactly like the one you already have, which you can create with [`maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) then pass to `translate()`:

```
turk = str.maketrans({"Ç":"C","ç":"c","Ğ":"G","ğ":"g","İ":"I","ı":"i",
        "Ö":"O","ö":"o","Ş":"S","ş":"s","Ü":"U","ü":"u"})

s = "Hellö ĞÇ 123"

s.translate(turk)
# 'Hello GC 123'
```

Comment: This is great but I need to learn how to code so hard way is the best for now, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a single map from Turkish to English. So A would map to A, B to B and so on, in addition to the turk dictionary you already have. You can then add the space, tab and any other character to the mapping.

Your code becomes a loop with a dictionary lookup using the get function.

Comment: Oh ok this makes sense now I add space, tabs and other things to dictionary, how can add numbers into this code ?